# Ask for stream of character input and print number of uppercase/lowercase characters

Tags: c, stream

Does this code look okay?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int case_letters();

int main(void)

{    
    case_letters();
    return 0;
}

int case_letters()

{
    int ch;
    int numOfUpper = 0;
    int numOfLower = 0;

    printf("please enter a some characters, and ctrl + d to see result\n");

    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (isdigit(ch))
        {
            printf("please enter a valid character\n");
            continue;
        }


        else if (isupper(ch))
        {
            numOfUpper++;
        }

        else if (islower(ch))
        {
            numOfLower++;
        }
    }

    return  printf("There are %d Uppercase letters, and %d Lowercase letters\n", numOfUpper, numOfLower);
}
```

Comment: There are more characters that upper()/lower() and digit(). See http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_4.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not seem to handle if the user enters a special character. ex: `* & %` etc...

Answer (score 6):

- It looks unusual to have newlines between the function statement and body since they're associated with each other.  This just adds extra lines and makes the code a little harder to read.
- If `case_letters()` is just supposed to print something at the end and not return a value, it should return `void` (no value), not `int`.  `main()` isn't doing anything with this function after calling it.
- [Unformatted outputs should use `puts()` instead of `printf()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454474/what-is-the-difference-between-printf-and-puts-in-c).
- As @Rhs has mentioned, your program doesn't handle special characters.  Based on [this](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_4.html) from @Loki Astari, there are additional types of characters and with accompanying testing functions.
- According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1782134/1950231), <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> only works on Mac OS and Linux.  For Windows, it's <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>.  All of this should be stated in the output in case the user is running this on Windows.
- Consider making this more modular for increased maintainability:

  1. keep letter counters for final output (in `main()`)
  2. collect each character from user
  3. determine if the character is a letter
  4. increment either counter if a letter is entered

  Here's what I came up with:

  ```
  #include <ctype.h>
  #include <stdbool.h> // add this library
  #include <stdio.h>

  bool valid_char(char ch)
  {
      if (isdigit(ch)) return false;

      // include additional non-letter checks...

      // if everything checks out:
      return true;
  }

  void update_counters(char ch, int* numOfUpper, int* numOfLower)
  {
      if (isupper(ch))
      {
          (*numOfUpper)++;
      }
      else if (islower(ch))
      {
          (*numOfLower)++;
      }
  }

  void get_letters(int* numOfUpper, int* numOfLower)
  {
      puts("Please enter some characters\n");
      puts("Press CTRL+D on Mac OS/Linux or CTRL+Z on Windows to see the results\n");
      char ch;

      while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF)
      {
          while (!valid_char(ch))
          {
              puts("Character must be a letter\n");
              ch = getchar();
          }

          update_counters(ch, numOfUpper, numOfLower);
      }
  }

  int main(void)
  {
      int numOfUpper = 0;
      int numOfLower = 0;

      int* upperPtr = &numOfUpper;
      int* lowerPtr = &numOfLower;

      get_letters(upperPtr, lowerPtr);

      printf("There are %d uppercase letters and %d lowercase letters\n", numOfUpper, numOfLower);
  }
  ```